# Populate WinUI3 TreeView

Tags: winui-3

Trying to fill a TreeView this way:

```
  auto root = tv.RootNodes();
  for (auto& group : e)
  {
    TreeViewNode tvn1;
    tvn1.Content(box_value(group.name));
    root.Append(tvn1);

    for (auto& subgroup : group)
    {
        auto name = sub.name;

        StackPanel sp;
        sp.Orientation(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Orientation::Vertical);
        TextBlock tb1;
        tb1.Text(name);
        sp.Children().Append(tb1);


        TreeViewNode tvn2;
        tvn2.Content(sp);

        tvn1.Children().Append(tvn2);
    }
}
```

The result is weird:

[image]

Does that mean that a TreeViewNode only accepts a .Content(box_value("string")) and not another StackPanel for example?

Can I have a TreeView in which each node is not a plain string?

Comment: This is because your TreeView has probably no template defined, and the default is something like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />`. This will output (Content).ToString(). You can put anything in a TreeViewNode but you need to define a proper DataTemplate depending on what you put in there. You can use a TreeView.ItemTemplateSelector. Have a look at this: https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/main/WinUIGallery/ControlPages/TreeViewPage.xaml ("A TreeView with ItemTemplateSelector") from WinUI3 Gallery app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tree-view

Comment: In general, you don't create TreeViews (or basically any XAML controls) using code, you define XAML, with templates, bindings, etc. and you use DataBinding (ItemsSources, etc.) in one or two way mode (bidirectional). WPF, UWP and WinUI3 were all developped with DataBinding everywhere in mind. Trying to escape that is recipe for weird problems.

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks, I guess I'm the old style gui that attempts to do it with code. I will take  look at the template definition and come back.

Comment: @SimonMourier my problem is that every sample I find is C# standalone and I 'm trying to do it in a normal desktop C++ project with WinUI windows available.

Comment: The C++ part should be quite similar but you'll need XAML indeed. You can find some interest in this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77638867/custom-control-library-in-islands-and-frame-navigate-accessviolationexception/ that uses a Winforms project (so, like a standard Win32 desktop project although it's C# again) to host an external WinUI3 library (follow github link in question). Otherwise, difficult to help w/o some reproducible project.

Comment: @SimonMourier I 'd like to see a project created with New Project -> Blank App, Packaged WinUI3 in desktop C++. This one creates a simple pushbutton. I could learn more If It would create a list that got it's items with databinding.

Comment: I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-property#add-a-property-of-type-bookstoreviewmodel-to-mainpage). I will take a look and let you know.

Comment: @SimonMourier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786420/winui3-c-data-binding

Comment: I've created a sample with full hierarchical binding https://github.com/smourier/WinUI3Cpp (everything is such more simple with .NET and C#...)