# WinUI3 C++ Data Binding

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-runtime, winui-3, c++-winrt

In reference to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77781045/populate-winui3-treeview?noredirect=1#comment137122774_77781045) about TreeView, I was suggested to use data binding to populate the items of the TreView.

I create a new Black App, Packaged, WinUI3 in Desktop C++ VS 2022 project.

This runs and displays the button

[image]

I change the MainWindow IDL:

```
namespace App1
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainWindow : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        MainWindow();
        String MyProperty;
    }
}
```

I change the .h

```
namespace winrt::App1::implementation
{
    struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow>
    {
        winrt::hstring j = L"TEXT 1";
        MainWindow()
        {
            // Xaml objects should not call InitializeComponent during construction.
            // See https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/nuget#initializecomponent
        }

        winrt::hstring MyProperty();
        void MyProperty(winrt::hstring);

        void myButton_Click(IInspectable const& sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);

        winrt::event_token PropertyChanged(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& value);
        void PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token);
        winrt::event<Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler> m_propertyChanged;
    };
}

namespace winrt::App1::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainWindow : MainWindowT<MainWindow, implementation::MainWindow>
    {
    };
}
```

I change the .cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("MainWindow.g.cpp")
#include "MainWindow.g.cpp"
#endif

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace winrt::App1::implementation
{
    winrt::hstring MainWindow::MyProperty()
    {
        return j;
    }

    void MainWindow::MyProperty(winrt::hstring nv)
    {
        j = nv;
        m_propertyChanged(*this, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Content" });
    }


    winrt::event_token MainWindow::PropertyChanged(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler const& handler)
    {
        return m_propertyChanged.add(handler);
    }

    void MainWindow::PropertyChanged(winrt::event_token const& token)
    {
        m_propertyChanged.remove(token);
    }


    void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        MyProperty(L"YO");
    }
}
```

And finally, the XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click" Content="{x:Bind MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}"></Button>
```

This only works once. It once calls my property and sets the "TEXT 1" to the button, but when `myButton_Click` is called the call to
`m_propertyChanged(*this, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"Content" });`

does nothing. The button doesn't update its content.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: When I do `m_propertyChanged(*this, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs{ L"" });` , that is, no "Content" string, it works.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work both ways because you specified `OneWay` mode (actually I don't really know why as it should work w/o it...):

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click" Content="{x:Bind MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}"></Button>
```

But you can declare it like this:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click" Content="{x:Bind MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"></Button>
```

But when you do this with C++/WinRT, you may get this type of error (note in .NET and C#, it would work just fine):

```
MainWindow.xaml.g.hpp(155,71): error C2665: 'winrt::to_hstring': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types
```

This is because `Content` is of `Object` type in IDL (aka `IInspectable`) while  your property is of `String` type in IDL (aka `hstring`) and there's no implicit conversion brought by `C++/WinRT`, see also https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/942

So you can fix it creating this conversion, for example (mimicking C++/WinRT's `base.h` `to_hstring` overloads) for example in MainWindow.xaml.h:

```
WINRT_EXPORT namespace winrt
{
  inline hstring to_hstring(IInspectable value)
  {
    auto pv = value.try_as<IPropertyValue>();
    if (pv && pv.Type() == PropertyType::String)
      return pv.GetString();

    return L"???";
  }
}
```

Also make sure your property is protected against infinite loop:

```
void MainWindow::MyProperty(hstring value)
{
    if (_myProperty == value)
        return;

    _myProperty = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(L"MyProperty");
}
```

I have created a sample app here: https://github.com/smourier/WinUI3Cpp