# {CustomResource} in Data Binding in C++ WinUI3

Tags: c++, xaml, winui-3, c++-winrt

While [working in data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786420/winui3-c-data-binding/77787601#77787601) in C++ WinUI3 app (and I 've learned a bit thanks to SimonMourier's [demo](https://github.com/smourier/WinUI3Cpp) I am also looking at the {CustomResource} data binding method.

I create the WinUI Packaged project

In MainWindow.xaml I 'd put:

```
<TextBlock   Text="{CustomResource Test1}"></TextBlock>
```

I will create a descentant of `winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Resources::CustomXamlResourceLoader`:

```
class CLX : public winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Resources::CustomXamlResourceLoader
{
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable GetResource(const winrt::param::hstring& resourceId, const winrt::param::hstring& objectType, const winrt::param::hstring& propertyName, const winrt::param::hstring& propertyType) const 
    {
        return winrt::box_value(L"hello");
    }
};
```

In the implementation I 'd add a variable:

```
CLX clx;
```

When the app is run, I get an expected exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE9E97567C (KernelBase.dll) in app1.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80004005 : 'No custom resource loader set.'.
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll!00007FFE3F265DD3: 80004005 - Unspecified error
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE9E97567C (KernelBase.dll) in app1.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x802B000A : 'No custom resource loader set. [Line: 12 Position: 22]'.
```

Now, in OnLaunched(),:

```
winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Resources::CustomXamlResourceLoader::Current(clx);
```

This causes a different exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE9E97567C (KernelBase.dll) in app1.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x802B000A : 'Markup extension could not provide value. [Line: 12 Position: 22]'.
```

So it sees that handler because it seems that it attemps to call it but the breakpoint there is not hit nor can be placed. It seems that the function is never compiled. Isn't that weird, isn't that a runtime feature?

Is my implementation of GetResource() correct?
I don't know what to do from here on.

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/customresource-markup-extension#remarks

You need to derive a custom class from `CustomXamlResourceLoader` and override `GetResource` method. Set `CustomXamlResourceLoader.Current` to reference your class in initialization logic. This must happen before any page-level XAML that includes the {CustomResource} extension usage is loaded.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT that's what I 'm doing but it doesn't call GetResource().

Comment: One place to set `CustomXamlResourceLoader.Current` is in the Application subclass constructor that's generated for you in the App.xaml code-behind templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this works at compile time:

```
class CLX : public winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Resources::CustomXamlResourceLoader
{
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable GetResource(const winrt::param::hstring& resourceId, const winrt::param::hstring& objectType, const winrt::param::hstring& propertyName, const winrt::param::hstring& propertyType) const 
    {
        return winrt::box_value(L"hello");
    }
};
```

The `GetResource` method won't be called as it's "just" a C++ method (that's why you get "Markup extension could not provide value" the error, because the method is never called) while the built-in `CustomXamlResourceLoader` implements this method as a method of the `ICustomXamlResourceLoaderOverrides` COM interface (which `CustomXamlResourceLoader` implements).

C++/WinRT provides a generated utility class for all WinRT types called `[Type]T` to wrap all this COM plumbing, ie: it will make sure your class implements `GetResource` *at COM level* so it's visible by external (to your project) pieces of code that only know COM exposure. This `[Type]T` is used everywhere in C++/WinRT samples for example in [Author APIs with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/author-apis) but it would deserve its own chapter IMHO...

So it will work if you declare it like this instead:

```
struct CLX : winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Resources::CustomXamlResourceLoaderT<CLX>
{
  IInspectable GetResource(const hstring& resourceId, const hstring& objectType, const hstring& propertyName, const hstring& propertyType) const
  {
    return winrt::box_value(L"hello");
  }
};
```

And instantiate like this:

```
void App::OnLaunched([[maybe_unused]] LaunchActivatedEventArgs const& e)
{
    auto clx = make<CLX>();
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Resources::CustomXamlResourceLoader::Current(clx);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are the god of Winui :)

Comment: Simon, one final question: I guess I can't use it easily on a <DataTemplate> for a list, it will repeatedly ask my custom loader with the same key and I couldn't know to which element it refers. Unless I can return a vector from it for the *entire* collection.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis - CustomResource is really for handing static resource (like for localization purpose, "sometext" => "sometranslatedtext"). You can't have it vary per context. The solution with XAML is to create objects and bind these objects, so when you bind to a list add a property that represents the object's resource (using customresource in code). Databinding is really the big big big to understand with XAML. Another solution is to use x:Bind instead of Binding. It's much more powerful, you can use methods etc. in XML but it sometimes reports weird XAML compilation errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have helped me a lot in understanding all that stuff.