Can native Win32 exe show a WinUI3 Page?
I need to show a WinUI3 page from a native Win32 exe. I cannot make modifications to the Win32 exe. The architecture is like this:

native Win32 .exe -> links to a C++/CLI dll with a known native C++ interface
C++/CLI dll -> references and makes calls into a C# .NET8 Class Library
C# .NET8 Class Library -> contains WinUI3 pages & controls.

(We also use the C# .NET8 class library's pages from a different WinUI3 exe as well)
(Also, we cannot change the native win32 exe. It is not under our control)
We've had this architecture for generations of MS technologies and always found a way to make it work with WinForms and then with WPF. But now we have WinUI3...
I'm not finding any examples other than
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5359576/WinUI3-in-Existing-Win32-Applications
and when I clone the example repo, it does not work (perhaps out of date due to the various betas that WinUI went through?)
Can this be achieved? If so, any advice on examples or documentation of the relevant calls that need to be made to set this up?
Thanks!

There are dozens of just official examples of using C++ with WinUI3, what do you mean by "I'm not finding any examples other than"? What's the problem with them?

Somewhere the .Net runtime need to be loaded to be able to run .net code. I'm guessing this is done in the c++/cli assembly? That might need to be configured somehow, at the very least it needs to load the correct runtime version. So you might want to post an example of that code.

The technology is called "Xaml Islands". It's documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands/xaml-islands (the doc is outdated, and mentions UWP but principles remains). The official sample is this one https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/tree/main/Samples/Islands but it's brain dead, it needs some massaging: delete nuget.config and change some files, here's a version that works with todays's packages https://pastebin.com/raw/J9bU9jL5) here is what it looks like https://i.imgur.com/z6tfAa9.png

@SimonMourier - this is good info, I was aware of Xaml Islands  but thought they only applied to WPF and UWP.  However, looking at the sample, there are lots of changes to required to the main message loop of the .exe. See above, we do not have access to change the native .exe (we are providing a 'plug in' to another entity's exe). I'm kind of hesitant to subclass the exe's main window loop. Do you think the Xaml Island concept can be implemented entirely in elements #2 and #3 above, without any changes to #1?

@Blindy - thanks for the reply. The question was not about how to implement WinUI3 code using C++, but rather how to marry a native Win32 C++ exe (that we don't have access to change) to some modern WinUI3 pages.

Win32 has no concept of "plugin" or "control", it knows only windows (it had OLE in-place activation but this is now legacy). Subclassing should work but playing with a parent you don't own at all can be risky. There's always the need for some kind of negotiation/coop between a parent/owner window and its children (mostly for input/mouse/keyboard/focus, size) it was the case for Winforms (easier since it's fully HWND based) and WPF that had special classes for that, that were not exempt of issue in the general case. Not sure how your #2 and #3 work exctly you should provide reproducing code.

It's still not clear what exactly you're trying to do, are you trying to insert Xaml content into a Win32 window? It doesn't sound like it, and that's what Xaml Islands are for, so your excitement for them is even more confusing. Your explanations in general seem to be only buzzwords (.Net, WinUI3, Win32) with absolutely no descriptions of what you actually have and are trying to do.

@SimonMourier   - Win32 doesn't have the concept of 'plug in' but it is easy enough to implement that architecture/design pattern/paradigm using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.  The .exe (#1 above) is a Win32 C++ app, written using MFC.  It calls LoadLibrary() to dynamically load #2 above, and uses GetProcAddress to get known names of native C/C++ functions. Suppose one of these function names is 'ShowDialog'.  When the .exe #1 calls 'ShowDialog' into #2 above, the implementation in #2 is to pass this on, via C++/CLI to (#3) which should display a WinUI3 Window ...

... continued
I have made this "#1 (making a function call) ->#2->#3 (showing a window)" work through the era of WinForms, and thru the era of WPF.  Now I am having difficulty making it work in the era of WinUI3, hence this post.
I appreciate any help you can provide.
(I do not need to display a WinUI3 control inside the native Win32 application's UI. I only need to show  modal and modeless dialog boxes)

This is the reduced version of what I see as being a "plugin" but that doens't change much, you still need quite a bit of infrastructure to run a WinUI3 window/page (which comes a long way from UWP initially) and this has to go through Xaml Islands. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77638867/custom-control-library-in-islands-and-frame-navigate-accessviolationexception/77640573#77640573 explains how to do it from Winforms, final code is https://github.com/nikolayvpavlov/Session_WindowsDesktop2024 the difference in your case is you don't have a Winforms App, but that may help

Thanks @SimonMourier, this is a good lead. I'll take a look and follow up with findings and/or questions.

Here is sample code for a regular Win32 desktop application which knows nothing about WinUI3 (note: WinAppSDK 1.6 needs to be installed for the sample to work but if it's not, you'll be automatically pointed to it). It's main message loop is completely standard:

Click on "Show WinUI3 Window menu item" to add WinUI3 content to it:

This uses the "Xaml Islands" technology, through the DesktopWindowXamlSource class. You can refer to official documentation here Host WinRT XAML controls in desktop apps (XAML Islands). It's talking about UWP, but the general principles are the same.
Click on it and a WinUI3 ContentDialog is shown:

Full code is available at https://github.com/smourier/Win32ShowsWinUI3
Here's the C++ code portion to host .NET Core directly from C++, inspired from the official .NET Hosting Sample:
hostfxr_initialize_for_dotnet_command_line_fn init_for_cmd_line_fptr = nullptr;
hostfxr_initialize_for_runtime_config_fn init_for_config_fptr = nullptr;
hostfxr_get_runtime_delegate_fn get_delegate_fptr = nullptr;
hostfxr_run_app_fn run_app_fptr = nullptr;
hostfxr_close_fn close_fptr = nullptr;
component_entry_point_fn _showWindowFn = nullptr;

bool load_hostfxr()
{
  char_t buffer[2048];
  auto buffer_size = sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(char_t);
  auto rc = get_hostfxr_path(buffer, &buffer_size, nullptr);
  if (rc != 0)
    return false;

  auto lib = LoadLibrary(buffer);
  if (!lib)
    return false;

  init_for_config_fptr = (hostfxr_initialize_for_runtime_config_fn)GetProcAddress(lib, "hostfxr_initialize_for_runtime_config");
  get_delegate_fptr = (hostfxr_get_runtime_delegate_fn)GetProcAddress(lib, "hostfxr_get_runtime_delegate");
  close_fptr = (hostfxr_close_fn)GetProcAddress(lib, "hostfxr_close");

  return (init_for_config_fptr && get_delegate_fptr && close_fptr);
}

load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer_fn get_dotnet_load_assembly(const char_t* config_path)
{
  void* load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer = nullptr;
  hostfxr_handle cxt = nullptr;
  auto rc = init_for_config_fptr(config_path, nullptr, &cxt);
  if (rc != 0 || !cxt)
  {
    close_fptr(cxt);
    return nullptr;
  }

  rc = get_delegate_fptr(cxt, hdt_load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer, &load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer);
  close_fptr(cxt);
  return (load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer_fn)load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer;
}

int ShowWinUI3Window(HWND hwnd)
{
  if (!_showWindowFn)
  {
    auto loaded = load_hostfxr();
    if (!loaded)
    {
      MessageBox(nullptr, L"Error: cannot load .NET Core.", L"Win32ShowsWinUI3", 0);
      return 0;
    }

    auto filePath = wil::GetModuleFileNameW();
    PathCchRemoveFileSpec(filePath.get(), lstrlen(filePath.get()));

    // load the WinUI3ClassLibrary runtime config 
    // note the .NET library must declare <EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading> to generate such a file
    wil::unique_cotaskmem_string rtPath;
    PathAllocCombine(filePath.get(), L"WinUI3ClassLibrary.runtimeconfig.json", 0, &rtPath);

    auto load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer = get_dotnet_load_assembly(rtPath.get());
    if (!load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer)
    {
      MessageBox(nullptr, L"Error: cannot load 'WinUI3ClassLibrary' assembly", L"Win32ShowsWinUI3", 0);
      return 0;
    }

    // load the WinUI3ClassLibrary.dll
    wil::unique_cotaskmem_string dllPath;
    PathAllocCombine(filePath.get(), L"WinUI3ClassLibrary.dll", 0, &dllPath);

    auto hr = load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer(
      dllPath.get(),
      L"WinUI3ClassLibrary.SampleWindow, WinUI3ClassLibrary",
      L"ShowWindow",
      nullptr,
      nullptr,
      (void**)&_showWindowFn);

    if (!_showWindowFn)
    {
      MessageBox(nullptr, L"Error: cannot load 'ShowWindow' function.", L"Win32ShowsWinUI3", 0);
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return _showWindowFn((void*)hwnd, sizeof(void*));
}

Here's the code in .NET library that enables WinUI3 in the hosting application (this library has been created from the standard WinUI3 class library), using the Bootstrap Class to initialize the WinAppSDK:
private static DummyApp? _app;

// this is called by the Win32 app (see hosting.cpp)
// in this sample, args is the parent HWND, sizeBytes is unused
public static int ShowWindow(nint args, int sizeBytes)
{
    // ask for WinAppSDK 1.6
    if (!Bootstrap.TryInitialize(0x00010006, string.Empty, new PackageVersion(), Bootstrap.InitializeOptions.OnNoMatch_ShowUI, out var hr))
        return hr;

    if (_app == null)
    {
        // comment this line if you don't want WinUI3 styles
        _app = new DummyApp();
        DispatcherQueueController.CreateOnCurrentThread();
    }

    var _source = new DesktopWindowXamlSource();
    _source.Initialize(Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(args));

    var button = new Button()
    {
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        Content = "Click me!",
    };

    var grid = new Grid() { Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue) };
    grid.Children.Add(button);

    button.Click += async (s, e) =>
    {
        var contentDialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
            XamlRoot = grid.XamlRoot,
            Title = "Information",
            Content = "Hello from WinUI 3!",
            CloseButtonText = "OK"
        };
        await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
        _source.Dispose();
    };

    _source.Content = grid;
    return 0;
}

// this is needed for proper XAML support with WinUI3 styles
private sealed class DummyApp : Application, IXamlMetadataProvider
{
    private readonly XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider provider = new();
    private readonly IXamlMetadataProvider _myLibProvider;

    public DummyApp()
    {
        // find the generated IXamlMetadataProvider for this lib
        var type = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().First(t => typeof(IXamlMetadataProvider).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.GetCustomAttribute<GeneratedCodeAttribute>() != null);
        _myLibProvider = (IXamlMetadataProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(type)!;
    }

    public IXamlType GetXamlType(Type type)
    {
        var ret = provider.GetXamlType(type);
        ret ??= _myLibProvider.GetXamlType(type);
        return ret;
    }

    public IXamlType GetXamlType(string fullName)
    {
        var ret = provider.GetXamlType(fullName);
        ret ??= _myLibProvider.GetXamlType(fullName);
        return ret;
    }

    public XmlnsDefinition[] GetXmlnsDefinitions()
    {
        var ret = provider.GetXmlnsDefinitions();
        ret ??= _myLibProvider.GetXmlnsDefinitions();
        return ret;
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new XamlControlsResources());
        base.OnLaunched(args);
    }
}

Note: you can also use WinUI3 "full" windows, but you can't run them w/o Application.Start, something like this just after Bootstrap.TryInitialize:
Application.Start(p =>
{
    var window = new SampleWindow();
    window.Activate();
});

However, there are issues when these windows are closed to reopen them (not sure if they are not bugs... but we're not really in a WinUI3 "app"). DesktopWindowXamlSource is really the sanctified way.
Note if you don't use the DummyApp class, the WinUI3 style will use the hosting Win32 style:


This is great! I will try this ASAP and report back. Thank you!

Perfect, works just as explained on my PC.  It definitely was not as straightforward as it was to make this work with WinForms and WPF. Thanks 1000%!
(BTW, what were your resources to arrive at this solution?)

@user1757226 - I've used my own answers in the same area https://stackoverflow.com/a/78472867/403671 but otherwise, you have all the known links :-)

Thank again! A followup when implementing this: I ran into more issues, that I also see in your example when I try to add these features: When I initialize log4net using XmlInitialize("myconfig.config"), the VS output window shows errors: "System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize
---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform."
and when I try to use IHostBuilder.Build() I get an exception that "EVentLog Access is not supported on this platform". Any ideas what isn't getting initialized properly? Thx!

... continued.... I can post in a new SO question with some more details and relevant example code if it helps. I can only give so much detail in the limited # of characters allowed in these comments.

You should ask another question, with a reproducing project.

Here is the same thread you could refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2120416/can-native-win32-exe-show-a-winui3-page

It seems showing WinUI3 content from a native Win32 exe is not
possible in a robust manner.

